# R find correlations between dataframes of different sizes

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation, sapply

I have two data frames with the same number of columns but different numbers of rows. I am trying to run correlation tests for all of the rows. I am able to do this with a for loop but because of the size of the dataset it is not a feasible option. I have found solutions for finding correlations of equal size data frames but I am not sure how to adapt these solutions.

Here is my for loop solution that works for smaller datasets.

```
c.mg.spearmanB = data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(brainMicroRNAs)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(brainGenes)) {
    miRNA = brainMicroRNAs[i,]
    gene = brainGenes[j,]
    #calculate correlations and add to dataframe
    c.mg.spearmanB[i,j] = cor.test(miRNA, gene, method="spearman", exact=F)$p.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many R functions expect observations to be rows, and variables to be columns. You appear to have flipped this around. No worries, we can transpose and use the normal `cor` function.

Some example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12), ncol = 3))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15), ncol = 3))
```

Now calculate the correlations:

```
cors <- t(cor(t(df1), t(df2)))
```

If you need p-values, we can do that manually, using vectorized functions:

```
df <- ncol(df1) - 2
t_vals <- cors * sqrt(df) / sqrt(1 - cors ^ 2)
p_vals <- 2 * min(pt(t_vals, df), pt(t_vals, df, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

Those p-values are two-sided.

And to check, if it all worked:

```
cor.test(unlist(df1[3, ]), unlist(df2[3, ]))
# Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  unlist(df1[3, ]) and unlist(df2[3, ])
# t = -0.015874, df = 1, p-value = 0.9899
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# sample estimates:
#         cor 
# -0.01587196 
cors[3, 3]
# [1] -0.01587196
p_vals[3, 3]
# [1] 0.9898952
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loops is not recommeded. Use df.corr of pandas instead. Merge the two dfs and then run the corr. If possible provide samples of datasets.

Comment: They are using R, not python.

Comment: Using reticulate and calling python is easier imho even in such a case if vectorized corr is not available in R dfs.